# Link with File's Owner problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, interface-builder

I created a nib file "WebViewController.xib". And try to link the UIView with File's Owner. 
But it doesn't work. Also sometimes with other nib files, I deleted a connection from 
View Connections->Referencing Outlet, then tried to connect again, but it can't link with File's Owner anymore.

How to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Tags are intended to help people who can answer your question find it.  People routinely look for questions with tags that correspond to their centers of interest.
I can pretty much assure that no-one is looking for any of the link, with, file, owner, problem tags.
There is a list of meaningful tags on the site (examples: latex, c, static-analysis). Does your problem happen designing an interface in XCode? There is an xcode tag for starters. Also consider objective-c, interface-builder

Comment: I think this is an iphone question, so I re-tagged it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the class of File's Owner to be `UIViewController` (or appropriate subclass)?

Comment: You've just given me a small piece of the puzzle! Thanks!